# New log files created under invalid group name

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny application that works locally, but the version that exists in Shiny Server crashes. When I attempt to read the log it is assigned to the group "2111" as seen in the last line below. The trouble is there is no group in our system with the name "2111," it is invalid and I get "permission denied" when I attempt to access it. For each file my system administrator can change the permissions so that I can read them, but any new file is created with the invalid group "2111" and I have to go through the process of having permissions changed again.

```
-rw-r----- 1 shiny hadoop 199 Oct  9 12:40 hello-shiny-20171009-124038-50604.log
-rw-r----- 1 shiny hadoop 199 Nov 13 17:44 hello-shiny-20171113-174423-34160.log
-rw-r----- 1 shiny hadoop 199 Nov 21 16:11 hello-shiny-20171121-161157-31691.log
-rw-r----- 1 shiny hadoop 199 Oct  9 12:27 prediction-shiny-20171009-122742-3223.log
-rw-r----- 1 shiny hadoop 198 Jan  3 11:47 prediction-shiny-20180103-114746-18552.log
-rw-r----- 1 shiny hadoop 198 Jan 16 12:33 prediction-shiny-20180116-123306-21825.log
-rw-r----- 1 shiny   2111 198 Jan 23 18:33 prediction-shiny-20180123-183308-33001.log
```

How do I prevent the log file from being made under the invalid group "2111?"

As a reference, here is the contents of /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as :HOME_USER: shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

# Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

# Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

# When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
# an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
directory_index on;
}
}
```

Comment: What does `ls -la` look like for the log directory? Any sticky bits set? Does `find / -gid 2111` show any files elsewhere with that group owner?

Comment: `ls -la` doesn't return anything unusual in addition to what is seen in `ls -l`, just the `.` and `..` directories. `find / -gid 2111` does show other files with that group owner. However, the `groups` command does not list "2111" as a group.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering what the permission bits and ownership look like for `.`.

`groups` will list your user's groups, and will only show the name, not the GID. (Though if you're seeing the GID in the listing, that typically means the group doesn't exist.)

Comment: This has been resolved, the system administrator changed the user to a valid primary group.